# Meaning of このくらいに

Tags: grammar

I have some difficulty to correctly analyze the structure このくらいに in the sentence

Context: a person who holds responsibilities has laughed a lot and she says

> わたしのストレス発散は**このくらいに**しておいて.
>
> My stress has disappeared to this extent ???

I am just a bit puzzled to see この before のくらい

Comment: このくらい means "this much".

Comment: 発射 ("to launch") is perhaps a typo for 発散?

Comment: thanks naruto, yes it was a typo

Comment: ストレス発散 is letting off steam (stress release).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some help, I publish the translation.

Here くらい has the meaning of 程度 “degree, extent”.

Thus このくらいにしておいて means litterany “do to the extent”, hence “do not go further than (this extent)”.

Its use is very common

> “今日はこのくらいにしておこう”
> That's all for today. (we stop to this extent)

So the sentence means

> I've let off enough steam for today.

Answer (score 4):

「このくらいにしておいて」is probably a set phrase meaning to allow the person some slack, "let it go" or "leave it at that".

> わたしのストレス発散はこのくらいにしておいて.

Let me have this much as a stress release.